# set global variable in the beginning ROS

Tags: python, global-variables, ros

How can I set the global variable in the beginning of the publisher?
**I want to initialize the global variable once in the beginning and use it**

```
def callback_initial(sensor_img):
    global initial_mean
    global initial_var
    bridge = CvBridge()
    cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(sensor_img, desired_encoding='passthrough')
    initial_mean, initial_var = get_intensity(cv_image)

def callback(sensor_img):
    bridge = CvBridge()
    cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(sensor_img, desired_encoding='passthrough')
    mean, var = get_intensity(cv_image)
    mean_dv = (abs(initial_mean - mean) / initial_mean) * 100.0
    var_dv = (abs(initial_var - var) / initial_var) * 100.0

class PublishThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, rate):
    super(PublishThread, self).__init__()
    self.publisher = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size = 1)
    self.x = 0.0
    self.y = 0.0
    self.z = 0.0
    self.th = 0.0
    self.speed = 0.0
    self.turn = 0.0
    self.condition = threading.Condition()
    self.done = False
    if rate != 0.0:
        self.timeout = 1.0 / rate
    else:
        self.timeout = None
    
    self.start()

def run(self):
    global global_mean_val
    twist = Twist()
    
    while not self.done:
        self.condition.acquire()
        # Wait for a new message or timeout.
        self.condition.wait(self.timeout)

        # Copy state into twist message.
        twist.linear.x = self.x * self.speed
        twist.linear.y = self.y * self.speed
        twist.linear.z = self.z * self.speed
        twist.angular.x = 0
        twist.angular.y = 0
        twist.angular.z = self.th * self.turn

        self.condition.release()

        # Publish.
        self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("/realsense/color/image_raw", Image, callback)
        if (global_mean_val < 1):
              self.publisher.publish(twist)
        else:
              print("COLLISION ANTICIPATED FOR MEAN CHANGE: {}, AVOIDING COLLISION!".format(global_mean_val))
```

Through this code, I am trying to save the image's mean and variance in the beginning and detect the object once the mean and variance gets changed drastically. So, I am trying to store the initial value of image's mean and variance.

Comment: You need to be a little more specific. What do you mean by set the value once in the publisher? Do you mean you want to just publish a value at startup, or do you want to store the first value received by a subscriber?